# Variance of a 2D random walk

Tags: random-variables, random-walk, variance

let define a 2D random walk by

$$
\sum_i A_i X_i
$$

where $A=[\cos(\theta)\ \sin(\theta)]^T$, $\theta$ is a random variable in the range $[0,2\pi]$ and $X$ is a scalar random variable between $[-1,1]$.
$\theta$ and $X$ have uniform distribution and they are independent.

1. The random walk can be split to two random walks in $x$ and $y$. Then, we end up to two variances $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$. How can we compute the variance of the 2D walk based on $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$? Maybe $\sqrt{\sigma_x ^2 + \sigma_y ^2}$?
2. If we calculate the variance of the vector $AX$, we end up to a $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix.
   I assume this should end to an identical result. But how?

Comment: the variance of the 2d walk won't only depend of the variance on the walk in each axis. Its also depends on the covariance between the axises

Comment: I observe that no distribution information is given, and no independence assumptions have been imposed. It is also not clear what is meant by "the variance of the 2d walk"?  What is the definition of variance of a vector? Is it the variance of each component?

Comment: Are $\theta$ and $X$ uniformly distributed. One can assume it but **it is much better** if you say it.

Comment: @BinyaminR How one can compute the covariance? Does the variance of the 2D vector end to a scalar or a vector?

Comment: @Michael They have uniform distribution and also they are independent. Actually i don't know. For a 1D case it is clear. But about a vector? If we see the variance as a mean square displacement, shouldn't we end to a scalar?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes they have uniform distribution and they are independent.

Comment: The variance of a scalar RV is a scalar ; the variance of a vector RV $(x,y)$ is a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_x^2&Cov(x,y)\\Cov(x,y)&\sigma_y^2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: In that case you can define random vector $W_n = \sum_{i=1}^n A_iX_i$ and you want to find the covariance matrix of $W_n$, namely $E[(W_n-E[W_n])(W_n-E[W_n])^T]$.  You can show $E[W_n]=0$ and so you want $$E[W_nW_n^T] = E\left[(\sum_{i=1}^n A_iX_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n A_jX_j)^T\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE[A_iA_j X_iX_j^T]$$ and there are lots of cancellations/simplifications possible due to independence.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. are $x$ and $y$ independent according to the definition of $A=[\cos(\theta)\ \sin(\theta)]^T$ ?

Comment: No, they aren't independent. Would they be, we would have $\underbrace{P(x>1/\sqrt{2} \ \& \ y>1/\sqrt{2})}_{=0}=\underbrace{P(x>1/\sqrt{2})}_{\ne 0}.\underbrace{P(y>1/\sqrt{2})}_{\ne 0}$ (the LHS is equal to $0$ because we cannot have $x^2+y^2>1$).